# Swap static block positions via xml

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, xml, static-block

As described in the title i want to change the position of 2 static blocks but i don't want to mess with their css.
I present my xml below:

```
  <reference name="tops1">
              <block type="cms/block" name="jmslideshow">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>jmslideshow</block_id></action>
              </block>
            </reference>
            <reference name="tops2">
              <block type="joomlart_jmtabs/core" name="jmtabs" >
                  <action method="addTabs_staticblock">
                    <title>Trending</title>
                    <identifier>trending</identifier>
                  </action>
                  <action method="addTabs_staticblock">
                      <title>best seller</title>
                      <identifier>best-seller</identifier>
                  </action>
                  <action method="addTabs_staticblock">
                      <title>New arrival</title>
                      <identifier>new-arrival</identifier>
                  </action>
              </block>
            </reference>
            <reference name="tops3">
              <block type="cms/block" name="collections">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>collections</block_id></action>
              </block>
            </reference>
            <reference name="mass-bottom">
              <block type="cms/block" name="gift">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>gift</block_id></action>
              </block>
            </reference>
            <reference name="bots1">
              <block type="cms/block" name="advantage">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>advantage</block_id></action>
              </block>
              <block type="cms/block" name="testimonials">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>testimonials</block_id></action>
              </block>
            </reference>
```

and to be more specific i want to change positions between `jmtabs` and `gift` in the mass-bottom.
Actually to be more specific i want `jmtabs` to show after `gift` in the mass-bottom.
How can that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Magento the `before="child.block.name"` and `after="child.block.name"` attributes are used to define the order of child blocks in the core/text_list blocks. If those attributes are not specified then the blocks will render in the order that Magento reads them.

Refer below for more [details](http://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/magento-tutorials/xml-blocks-local-xml/)

http://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/magento-tutorials/xml-blocks-local-xml/

Comment: does this helped?

Comment: It helped  me to understand how static blocks work, but i am still reading in order to make the changes that i want.

Comment: :) there is no shortcuts.. ;)

Comment: It seems a good tutorial but it does not clarifies things up, at least that's my personal opinion, so i can't mark it as solution, thank you anyway tho. If you have something for me to check out , it would be appreciated.